# Undo Enumerable.AsParallel(), going back to serial mode

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

Assume you have a LINQ query like

```
source.AsParallel().Where(expensiveOperation).Select(cheapOperation)
```

I suppose in this case `Select` also runs in parallel execution mode. Maybe it's just a cheap operation like `i => i*2`, so is there a way to stop parallel execution at a point of querying with chained methods?

(maybe like `.AsParallel().Where(expensiveOp).AsSerial?().Select(cheapOp)`?)

Comment: I belive PLINQ is smart and executes the `Where()` together with the `Select()`. So, even when `Select()` is cheap, you probably don't need to force it to be sequential. But you'll have to measure that for yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The operation you're looking for is [`AsSequential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383949.aspx).

```
source.AsParallel().Where(expensiveOp).AsSequential().Select(cheapOp)
```

Comment: looks like I was wrong on vocabulary haha. Thanks for noting. I literally looked for `AsSerial()` in docs for a few mins.